# how to open pdf file using pypdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I tried to open a pdf file using `pypdf` in Google Colab using

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf2
with open("sample.pdf", "r+") as f:
   pdf = pdf2.PdfFileReader(f)
```

but I get following error:

```
UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks
```

Changing the mode form "r" to "r+" does not resolve the problem. What is the cause of this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: sorry, I forgot putting the error message,

Comment: edit your question to put the error message

Comment: Have you uploaded the file to colab?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I uploaded the file to colab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/489), you need to open with `mode='rb'`.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf2

with open ("sample.pdf", "rb") as f:
   pdf = pdf2.PdfFileReader(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple program to open a pdf file and print its first page will be as following,

```
import PyPDF2 

pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb') 

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

print(pdfReader.numPages) # printing number of pages in pdf


pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 


print(pageObj.extractText()) # extracting text from page 0


pdfFileObj.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

To open a pdf file you can write this code

```
import os
os.startfile('sample.pdf')
```

I hope this works!

Comment: Consider editing your answer. OP asked how to open a pdf with pypdf2 specifically. Also os.startfile is only available on Windows